# Does Keras cache activations if lower layers are frozen?

Tags: keras, transfer-learning

I've been experimenting a bit with gradually adding layers to a model, while freezing N layers and only leaving the N+1th layer trainable. In my mind, the time to train any layer should be roughly constant where I need to only run inference through the N frozen layers once in the first epoch, then use the activation from this inference to train what is essentially a single layer model. However, in practice I found that training times did increase a lot as I added more layers, leading me to believe that Keras has no caching behavior of this kind.

Or phared differently: When freezing layers, does keras still run inference through the entire model repeatedly in lower parts of the model that are static (during fitting)?